# removeFromSuperview when there is no addSubView issue

Tags: ios, addsubview

My code is working fine when I call `reloadData` method every second, it removes the *view* (when there is a *view*) and add the *subView*. The problem is when there is not a *subView* I get `exc_bad_access` issue that shows on the `[self.lbl1 removeFromSuperview]` function.

**my code**

```
-(void)reloadData

if (result1 > result2 &&  al == YES)
{
    lbl1 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 530, 550, 200)] autorelease];

    lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    lbl1.text = @"WARNING";
    lbl1.tag = 30;
    lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
    lbl1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl1.numberOfLines = 2;
    [self addSubview:lbl1];
}

    else if (result1 < result2 &&  al == YES){

    [self.lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Please where would be my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can there be a condition in your code when the 2nd if loop (`result1 < result2 &&  al == YES`) is called before the first one?

In that case, `lbl1` would not be added on the view or not be allocated and hence cannot be removed.

You need to check that if lbl1 exists, only then remove it from its superview.

```
if(self.lbl1) [self.lbl1 removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: It works when I put all `lbl1` label method with `SELF`. Thanks it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the label has the right superview

```
if (lbl1 && lbl1.superview == self) { // then lbl1 is already a subview of self
    [lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this in this condition

```
else if (result1 < result2 &&  al == YES)
{
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [self.lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove autorelease and make something like

```
 if (lbl1) {
        [lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
        [lbl1 release];        
    }
```

before `lbl1 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame...`

Comment: Thanks. but it doesn't work I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x2e777783)